# C ANSI Escape Code

Tags: c, cursor, dos, turbo-c, ansi-escape

How can I do cursor control with ANSI using escape sequences using Turbo C? Here I've provided a code, but it's not yet working in my TurboC.

```
main()
{
   while( getche() != '.' )
      printf("\x1B[B");
}
```

Comment: Why are you persisting in using Turbo C when everyone tells you to use something else. You are wasting your (and more importantly, our) time.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: I am not forcing you to waste your time. This is still a question which you can answer optionally. You don't know why I am using this one. My apologies sir!

Comment: Turbo C is actually implementing the C90 standard somewhat well. The main problem with it is that it mixes the C language with non-standard crap, and there is no easy way for a beginner to tell what's the C language, and what's crap. Modern compilers like GCC implement lots crap too, but there you have the option to shut the crap off with -std=c90 -pedantic.

Comment: Lundin, Did you mean -std=c99 or -std=iso9899:1990 (which is same as -std=c89)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the possibility that that output may be line buffered (meaning nothing may appear until you send a newline), you should probably also ensure that `ANSI.SYS` is loaded, since it's the device driver responsible for interpreting those sequences.

But I'm wondering *why* you're doing this. From memory (admittedly pretty *faded* memory), Turbo C has calls for doing this sort of thing, `gotoXY` and `clrscr` and such.

Comment: what's that ANSI.SYS? How can I load it? and where I can find it?

Comment: aside from that- If I'm not mistaken, the attribute of a character or string can be set using an ANSI escape sequence also.

Comment: This is becoming a real effort now, I'm having to go all the way into my brain stem to retrieve this stuff, with the possibility that I may be mis-remembering :-) It depends on which OS you're using. Under pre-NT, it was a device driver loaded by config.sys. For NT onwards, you had to add "DEVICE=%systemroot%\system32\ANSI.SYS" to your system32\config.nt file. That worked at least up until XP. I can't say for sure whether it worked on Vista onwards since I never used them.

Answer (score 0):

A way of putting escape character with printf() is:

```
printf("%c[B", 0x1b);
```

But usually (I don't know Turbo C), there are libraries for doing terminal related stuff in a portable way.